# Making a function to check if input word is a palindrome with Python with for and while loops

Tags: python, function, for-loop, while-loop, palindrome

I'm trying to make a program that checks if user's input word is a palindrome and asks words until the input is a palindrome. My problem is that I can't get my program to print anything and could use some tips to fixing it. This is what I have so far:

```
def palindrome(word):
    while True:
        word=input("Enter a word: ")
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if word[i]==word[(i+1)*-1]:
                print(f"{word} was a palindrome!")
                return True
            else:
                print("not a palindrome")
                return False
```

Comment: While there are issues with your function, your problem description seems off. It prints `'bob was a palindrome!'` just fine for me.

Comment: Did you actually call this function somewhere in your script ? Defining it not enough. Also the word parameter is useless, as you overwrite with input.

Answer (score 1):

You have easier ways to check if a word is a palindrome like : `word == word[::-1]`.
(Is the word equal to itself written in reverse)

```
def palindrome():
    word=input("Enter a word: ")
    if word == word[::-1]:
        print(f"{word} was a palindrome!")
    else :
        print("not a palindrome")
```

Anyway, to improve your program you can remove the `while True` boucle that isn't useful here, you do not need `word` as an argument since you define it in your function. Then you need a variable that can "remember" if a letter is not equal to the letter at the opposite position.

```
def palindrome():
    word=input("Enter a word: ")
    isPalindrome = True
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] != word[(i+1)*-1]:
            isPalindrome = False
    if isPalindrome:
        print(f"{word} was a palindrome!")
    else:
        print("not a palindrome")

palindrome()
```

They are many ways to improve this program to make it shorter / smarter but that should be a good place to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your function.. and you did not even make it a call so how it will work
try this

```
def palindrome():
    while True:
        word=input("Enter a word: ")
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if word[i]==word[(i+1)*-1]:
                print(f"{word} was a palindrome!")
                return True
            else:
                print("not a palindrome")
                return False
palindrome()
```